# excel exporting to pdf; graph placement offset

Tags: excel, pdf, export

I have some trouble with a document when exporting it to pdf with the builtin pdf export function of excel (2010).

I've generated a graph on my worksheet, with some colored cells arround it. Visually it looks good (even if I zoom on it with the ctrl key + mouse wheel). But when exporting, the graph overlap the surrounding cells.

For example, on the image bellow, I take a screenshot of my graph in excel (at top) and in pdf (at bottom). The red part is my graph (I've colored the background of the graph object). The graph have a black border. And just on the top of the graph, I've colored the background of a cell in blue. Normally, the graph must not overlap the blue cell, because I've manually place it bellow (cut the graph, select the cell bellow the blue one, and past the graph to this emplacement).

But we can see that:

- the black border overlap the blue cell (in excel and in pdf version; but it's not really my problem; I've understand that the border in excel object is at outside the object; and then overlapp surround objects/cells).
- the graph (in red + the border) has not the same place in excel and in pdf, there is a big offset (it's not a resize problem, this offset is present and the left side too). The place of the graph is more on the left and more on the top in pdf version than it can be!

(I'm using this to automatically generate reports; and the result is not visually good)

[image: excel graph placement problem]

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I can't replicate your problem, but I've had similar issues exporting Crystal Reports to PDF.  Here's 2 suggestions, neither of which is perfect and I couldn't try them first (again, sorry I couldn't replicate the problem):

1. Add a white row with a very small height between the graph and the cell.  It might even be visually more appealing than the 2 objects one on top of the other.
2. Make your graph's background transparent and hide the border.  Maybe add some extra white space at the top of your graph.  That way, they'll still overlap, but it won't be as obvious.

Comment: I've already thought about that, but it's not a solution, it's a workaround ;) And I also try to fit / aligh my graph on the left and on the right of that blue cell. But... I will probably use your solution number 2 in few days.